# Using Input::all() when uploading files in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

According to [this](http://daylerees.com/codebright/request-data), if you do the following

```
<?php

// app/routes.php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('form');
});

Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
    var_dump(Input::all());
});
```

We'll get the following:

```
array(0) { }
```

According to Dayle Rees, that is because files are stored in the $_FILES array and not in $_GET or $_POST. So when we change the second function to:

```
Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
    var_dump(Input::file('book'));
});
```

We get:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {<
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=><
  bool(false)<
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=><
  string(14) "codebright.pdf"<
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=><
  string(15) "application/pdf"<
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=><
  int(2370413)<
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=><
  int(0)<
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=><
  string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpPOb0vX"<
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=><
  string(9) "phpPOb0vX"<
}<
```

However, in my project, when I use Input::all(), I still get the correct output very identical to the above. The file I used is different, but I hope you get the point. Why is my projects giving different outputs from the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see into /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php,

```
/**
 * Get all of the input and files for the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function all()
{
    return array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->files->all());
}
```

which contains both files and other inputs.
Since CodeBright was started with laravel 3, ( http://goo.gl/NWltLh ), I suppose (but not sure), this section of code was updated later on Laravel 4.

Comment: So the book is wrong? What about the Input::file function?

Comment: The book might had older version of Laravel as I illustrated in the answer above.